# Using Instance Methods in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Can someone help me understand how to use instance methods in Sequelize? I've reviewed the documentation but have found it to be sparse. At present, I am trying to use setPassword and verifyPassword instance methods on my user model. When I try to call the code in the REPL, after having imported the user model and synced the DB, I get the following:

```
> models.User.setPassword('test');
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setPassword'
```

Here is the code for the user model:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('User', {
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false, validate: { isEmail: true } },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    firstName: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    lastName: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    companyName: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    admin: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: false,},
    forgotUrl: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
    forgotDate: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    lastLogin: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }
  }, {
    paranoid: true,
    instanceMethods: {
      setPassword: function(password, done) {
        return bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
          return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(error, encrypted) {
            this.password = encrypted;
            this.salt = salt;
            return done();
          });
        });
      },
      verifyPassword: function(password, done) {
        return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, res) {
          return done(err, res);
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Why the returns before all your callback calls?

Comment: the use of `this` in the `setPassword` instance method will fail to refer to the actual User instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instance method can be used on specific element instances eg.

```
models.User.find(123).success( function( user ) { 
    user.setPassword('test');
});
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense. Do you have any idea why I am getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function` from `return done()` when I run: `> models.User.find(1).success( function( user ) { user.setPassword('password'); });`

Comment: no idea . I'm using this construct in my project without a problem

Comment: surfearth. "done" is the second parameter to setPassword, which has to be a function as you call it "return done();". You aren't passing in a parameter, so "done" is undefined and is not a function.

Answer (score 3):

You define the function as:
`function(password, done)`

Yet you don't supply the done parameter.
Thus, the function leaves done as undefined and calling done() is executing an undefined function.

You could fix this in 3 ways:

1. Default done to a noop function `function () {}`
2. Only return `done()` if done is defined
3. Supply a done callback when calling the instance function.

The alternative is to refactor it to return a promise which it resolves on completion.